# Why is my character feeling sad?

Tags: animal-crossing-new-leaf

Every time I open my inventory.. or catch a fish I believe.. My character frowns. Is there something I can do to stop this? Its a bit annoying since I feel I am doing an ok job but if I stop to look at something or for something or catch something, suddenly they are grumpy.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

They're not sad, they're thinking. They've always done this when opening the menu to my recollection. Have someone take a picture of you when you're in deep thought and you'll probably be frowning too. It's just a natural human thing to do that's included as a bit of realism/personality for the character.

There's no way to stop it, it's just their animation.

Comment: Ah, well that explains that.. Deep thoughts when eyeing a common butterfly.. I will figure this game out!

Comment: @James Well, they're usually thinking "how much can I get for that butterfly..." - it takes a lot of thought to do instant appraisals :)

Comment: "Am I a man dreaming I am a butterfly, or is that butterfly dreaming that I am a man?  More importantly, how many bells can I get for that butterfly?"

Answer (score 0):

Your character isn't sad, he/she is deep in thought. Probably thinking about what things in your inventory should be sold, what should be kept, and what to dispose of. Also how many bells they can sell the stuff for. Use a mii mask and they just put their hand on their chin without changing expression, proving that they are thinking, not being sad.